# Runtime stack not loaded - Azure - Github Actions

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, github-actions

I am trying to create an app service using Azure. I'm having my java web application code in github and created the azure webapp with tomcat 9.0 runtime stack.

But when i try to connect with github actions, the runtime stack is not populated at all.

Has anyone run to similar issue and know how to overcome this ?

Answer (score 1):

Stack 'java-8' is currently not supported in Deployment Center via GitHub Actions.

[image]

Please check if you have configured the Java version to `Java 11`.

[image]

[image]

Comment: In fact it is otherway around.. i get a message which states java 11 is not supported by github actions. But in either cases, the runtime doesn't populate in my case.